# Type for any JSON-like object with specific subtypes

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

I need to limit users to use only JSON-like props (null, string, number, boolean and object or arrays with this primitives).

I have type for pure JSON:

```
export type SerializableObject = { [key: string]: Serializable }
export interface SerializableArray extends Array<Serializable> {}
export type Serializable = null | string | number | boolean | SerializableArray | SerializableObject
```

but some type is not assignable:

```
[...]    
Type '{ tabId: string; tabs: TabData[]; }' is not assignable to type 'SerializableObject'.
```

TabData is:

```
interface TabData {
  label: string
  body: string
}
```

**Is it possible to write type, which includes more specific types, but still JSON-like?**

Comment: The issue here is caused by [microsoft/TypeScript#15300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300); `TabData` is an `interface`, which has no implicit index signature, unlike what would happen if it were a `type` alias.  I'd suggest either using object literals or type aliases, or changing your `Serializable` to a generic constraint instead of a specific type

Comment: [Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#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-vDyKDNRBEdKAPSRgSqcL2IA)

Comment: Let me know if you want me to turn those into an answer or if they don't meet your needs (and if not, why not)

Comment: [another way](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2AOQPbAGIFcB2qAlhvlALxQaIrBQBkUAFAN5RxH4AmA-AFxQCXCADNOELlAC+UAD5Q2yAIYAbFf0HdR4yTPlslYMCpAah2-BOkBKANwAoUJCgBBAM4ApN6QA8AFQA+Cig3YAAnTgBzOSh8XABbOAgwmLgMDBUIJTJ5OLUYpngkVEwcAmJSBgUoAG0AaShOKABrCBAMESg-AF0Bdy9fP3ruoKk7e2RSUKglT28ySh8PKAgAD2AIbjdXOd8PAICmBAEPaxOKIIQHe04NsJElZGg-JTgAESVgJQV7KD+oFSvCAqAShCL4SK-f5pLggUHhKL2KT2RzgaDYdLBNhfOAASS48PBkVsUBxbgEL3enyUNW6JOREymdBE6QEGIwWNJr3xAgARLyADRcuDk2psQFJEFQflCmFw6W86TdaSM-DTNzJIiqIgAL1emXZwVmA3wTBZGDsUAA9FaqM0lCB7Mb5qwZgIAIyygQAJiFyAE5jEll01mttuQjW2yTCGDC9iAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose looking into the [type-fest](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest) library and its `JsonValue` type. Depending on your use-case it might be suitable for you.